# How do I write a code to search for the highest value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

So I made a method which searches an array which is part of the class CO2Data. Here's the method:

```
public static CO2Data highest (CO2Data []  arr2){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
CO2Data highestindex = arr2[0];
for (int i = 0; i<arr2.length; i++){
    if (arr2[i].getTotalCO2() > highestindex.getTotalCO2()){
        highestindex = arr2[i];
        }
    }
System.out.println(highestindex.getTotalCO2());
return highestindex;
}
```

The method finds the correct highest value however I want it to print out the country that that value is associated with. The values are taken from this data file:

```
"Country"   "Total CO2 2005 (million tonnes)"   "Road CO2 (million tonnes)" "Road CO2 per person (tonnes)"  "Cars per 1000 people"
10
USA 5951.13 1530.3  5.16    777
UK  2573.4  119.68  1.99    470
Italy   476.08  116.86  2   592
Germany 841.78  150.21  1.82    550
Canada  553.02  123.42  3.82    562
France  414.03  128.13  2.04    477
Russia  1575.44 114.69  0.8 178
Japan   1254.47 224.24  1.76    447
China   5100.6  228.02  0.3 17
India   1147.46 91.06   0.1 8
```

The number that the method printed out was 5951.13 but I want it to print out USA because that's the country that the number was associated with. I attempted to modify my highest method to try and associate the country with it but that code doesn't compile. So what's 
wrong with it?

```
public static CO2Data highest (CO2Data []  arr2){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
CO2Data highestindex = arr2[0];
CO2Data currentcountry = arr2[0].getCountry(sc.nextLine());
for (int i = 0; i<arr2.length; i++){
    if (arr2[i].getTotalCO2() > highestindex.getTotalCO2()){
        highestindex = arr2[i];
        currentcountry = arr2[i].getCountry(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
System.out.println(highestindex.getTotalCO2());
return highestindex;
}
```

Here's the CO2Data class:

```
public class CO2Data {

    private String country; //A private variable will prevent other users from accessng and chaning these variables. 
    private double totalCO2;
    private double roadCO2;
    private double CO2PerPerson;
    private int carsPerPerson;

    public CO2Data() { 
        country = "";//this sets the initial values for the different variables
        totalCO2 = 0;
        roadCO2 = 0;
        CO2PerPerson = 0;
        carsPerPerson = 0;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) { //to set the country you have to use the this command to access the private variable
        this.country = country; //you have to use this.country instead of just country because the string county has been declared as a private variable. 
    }

    public double getTotalCO2() {
        return totalCO2;
    }

    public void setTotalCO2(double totalCO2) {
        this.totalCO2 = totalCO2; //The this.item command allows you to access private variables. 
    }

    public double getRoadCO2() {
        return roadCO2;
    }

    public void setRoadCO2(double roadCO2) {
        this.roadCO2 = roadCO2;
    }

    public double getCO2PerPerson() {
        return CO2PerPerson;
    }

    public void setCO2PerPerson(double cO2PerPerson) {
        this.CO2PerPerson = cO2PerPerson;
    }

    public int getCarsPerPerson() {
        return carsPerPerson;
    }

    public void setCarsPerPerson(int carsPerPerson) {
        this.carsPerPerson = carsPerPerson;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ermm ... you are missing something pretty obvious here.

Hints ... in the form of rhetorical questions:

- What does
- What field contains the country of a `CO2Data` object?
- How do you get the value of that field?
- How do you print it?

Also ...

What is this line doing ... and why is it (obviously) wrong?

```
CO2Data currentcountry = arr2[0].getCountry(sc.nextLine());
```

(Look at the declaration for `getCountry`.  What is its purpose?  What arguments does it take?)

Answer (score 0):

You could rather sort the array on the required column say "Total CO2 2005" and take the first node for MAX

Comment: And how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my revised code

```
public static String highest (CO2Data []  arr2){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
CO2Data highestindex = arr2[0];
for (int i = 0; i<arr2.length; i++){
    if (arr2[i].getTotalCO2() > highestindex.getTotalCO2()){
        highestindex = arr2[i];
        }
    }
return highestindex.getCountry();
}
```

This code always works even if I modify carbon.data. I recently modified it so that uk is the highest value and it printed out uk.